# Why isn't Crosswalk being included in my apk?

Tags: meteor, meteor-cordova

```
$ meteor --version
1.2.0.1
$ meteor add crosswalk
$ meteor build ~/build --server X
```

Results in an `unaligned.apk` that is 2.8MB. From what I understand, Chromium (which is much larger than that) should be included in the packaged app, so it must not be making it into the apk? How can I diagnose why that isn't happening? `~/build/android/project`:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, with Crosswalk included I would expect the APK to be at least 20MB.

Did you look in the project/build/outputs/apk directory? There should be APKs for multiple architectures there.

Comment: Great, thank you! I had previously only used `~/build/android/unaligned.apk`, and did not know about the `apk` directory. Perhaps a note should be added to the `crosswalk` pkg readme and/or `meteor help build`.

Comment: I have inspected the outputs/apk directory and as you said I found and APK of 21MB (My app is only 1MB), so I think this one actually includes crosswalk.  The issue I notice is that all of the files in this directory have the "debug" word in their name...  I'm looking to upload a production APK to Google Play, so it seems to me that I need a release APK and not a debug APK...